# Script to merge PDF files with same name in G Suite set to weekly trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking for help compiling a code to merge PDF files with the same name in Google Documents.  I have a script that saves a spreadsheet as a PDF with a name which is a formatted date.  That said, there could be up to 7 with the same name.  I need to merge these into 1 PDF but I need to do it automatically set up on a weekly trigger.

Anything helps.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This combines the text of all PDF's in a folder

```
function combinePDFs() {
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1Zd_ty0O1WljjADzGQGrtUM57hvE5berT');
  var destFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1mHRFCwzqccJn83N7THnvZ8_Z-DCLeGOV');
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  var text='';
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var blob=file.getBlob();
    var resource={title:blob.getName(),mimeType:blob.getContentType()}
    var f=Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {ocr: true,ocrLanguage: "en"});
    var doc=DocumentApp.openById(f.id);
    text+=doc.getBody().getText() + '\n------------------------------------------------------------\n';
    DriveApp.getFileById(f.id).setTrashed(true);//trash intermediate files
  }
  var tf=DocumentApp.create('combined.doc');
  tf.getBody().setText(text);
  tf.saveAndClose();//combined text file
  var docblob=DocumentApp.openById(tf.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
  docblob.setName('combined.pdf');//
  destFolder.createFile(docblob);//combined PDF
  DriveApp.getFileById(tf.getId()).setTrashed(true);//trashed combined text file
}
```

[Reference from Amit Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359290/7215091)

[Drive.Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

[Setup a Time Based Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299820/7215091)

[Upload files with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15790713/7215091)