# How to use "ScriptApp.newTrigger("newTimer")" as a timer to activate a function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a simple function where I can start a timer with a button. After the timer is done (1 minute in this example), I want to execute another function and stop the timer.

I want to use a button to start the timer in a simple sheet to show a message when the timer is over.

```
function buttonTimer1min() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("timer1Minute")
  .timeBased()
  .after(5000)
  .create();

}

function timer1Minute(){

}
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299820/7215091

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: What's the actual issue? To create the button or to show the pop-up message?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information on the Apps Script website her [newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname) also check 
[Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) for more details about the methods you can use.